# PhpMyAdmin editable rows inside Cpanel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

There are threads here with similar issue, but none of them specifically inside Cpanel. And none of their solutions work.

Basically, I am using a WHM/Cpanel setup.

INside PhpMyAdmin, I changed the editing type in Settings --> Main Panel (inside Cpanel) but it still doesn't make the rows editable on click, or double click, in Safari/Chrome/Firefox. What am I missing?

The implementation is on WHM/Cpanel. So I can also change the main config file of PhpMyAdmin. I changed the /usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/.../config.inc.php where I had to add this line:

$cfg['GridEditing'] = 'double-click';

Then I saved the file, and restarted MySQL (not that that would help, but some site mentioned it), and refreshed phpmyadmin in my browser. No go. The rows in the Browse mode in a table are still uneditable.

The version is 4.0.4, which is the latest available in Cpanel.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to rule out browser problems - does the grid editing work for you on phpMyAdmin demo server? - http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/QA_4_0/

Comment: What's the password for that one?

Comment: User is root, password empty (see http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/ for more information)

Comment: Thanks for that. I signed in, and yes the rows (actually each of the columns) are editable. I am using latest Chrome on Mac OSX. Same with Safari, FF, etc. But in my WHM it doesn't work, despite the "doubleclick" settings in the config, and also the "Settings" tab in PHPMyAdmin itself.